# VBScript: Stop script when windows explorer is closed

Tags: vba, vbscript

How can I stop script from running when I close windows explorer? Here's my code.

```
Dim i
   CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """website1.com""", 0, False
   Wscript.Sleep 40000
   CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """website2.com""", 0, False
   Wscript.Sleep 40000

For i=1 to 10
   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
   WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
   Wscript.Sleep 1000
   WshShell.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
   Wscript.Sleep 40000          
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This counts the number of windows of interest and exist when 0

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Do 
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Count = 0
    For Each window in AllWindows
        window.refresh2 3
        Count = Count + 1
    Next
    If Count = 0 then Exit Do
    Wscript.sleep 5000
Loop
```

Or to refresh only two windows

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Do 
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Count = 0
    For Each window in AllWindows
        If window.locationname = "website1.com" or window.locationname = "website2.com" then
            window.refresh2 3
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Count = 0 then Exit Do
    Wscript.sleep 5000
Loop
```